# Post Formats in the context of the Database 'Save Post' function

Tags: custom-taxonomy, post-formats, save-post

I am trying to pick up an in-depth understanding of how post-formats relate to posts 'in the database' - i.e. what meta information when compiled together constitutes a post format.  And yes, I do mean a post format (NOT a post type).

All of the documentation I can find assumes a starting point where post_format is selected from the meta box on the 'New Post' page.  I'm working with a plugin (wootumblog) which uses a custom 'save_post' function, so need to understand more about how this actually works.

I see several tables involved including *wp_terms* (where the post_format slug is referenced against term_id) and *wp_term_relationships* (where the term_id is referenced against the post_id or object_id as the column is named) but I'm unclear as to whether wp_postmeta needs to be updated or are these two 'terms' tables sufficient for wordpress to work with?

I basically have a problem integrating the wootumblog and wpmu sitewide tags plugins together, and suspect this may be caused by the different protocols they use to save a post.

This seems a pretty barren area for documentation, so if someone speaks the post format lingo, it would be really useful to outline how it all works at a 'data' level.

Answer (score 6):

Post format for the post is `term` of native `post_format` taxonomy.

It can be set for the post by [`set_post_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_format) function. As with any taxonomy you can also use some deeper level function, but really there is no need. And I definitely don't recommend to try and deal with terms and taxonomies directly in database (sanity at risk).

Core seems to be [setting it in `edit_theme()` function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.1/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L183).

Comment: Thanks for that link, that's what I thought.  The wootumblog plugin uses set_post_format() when creating a new post, however the wpmu sitewide tags plugin uses wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, $tax, array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) which feels like it's achieving something quite different.   The end result is that SWT pages plugin does not pick up the post format when creating the entry in the tags blog.

Comment: @DoctorDR sorry, I have no idea about that plugin's purpose/functionality so you lost me there :)

Comment: The wootumblog plugin uses a custom dashboard widget to publish new posts - as asides, video, image, quote, link.. http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/woo-tumblog/ whilst the wpmu sitewide tags plugin is used on a Wordpress multisite installation to aggregate blog posts from across the network into a single 'tags blog' which can then display a list of network-wide posts or global tags - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-sitewide-tags/.  The sitewide tags plugin reads the source blog and then creates a duplicate entry with 'just' enough meta data in the main blog.

Comment: @DoctorDR does plugin tries to fetch post format and fails? or doesn't try at all? Getting post format is as easy with [`get_post_format()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_format)...

Comment: That's the nub of my question really - the wpmu sitewide tags plugin contains no `get_post_format()` instructions, instead the call it uses for such meta data is `wp_get_object_terms`, so I'm asking whether this is why the process fails to replicate the data successfully.

Comment: @Rarst post here on adding post format support to SWT http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/sitewide-tags-update/